# Async Http angular request

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm using angular 6, now I'm updating my resource istance in this way

```
this.user = api.getUser();

public getUser(): User {
  const myHeader = new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.session.getAccessToken(),
  }).append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.http.get < User > (API_URL + '/users', {
      headers: myHeader
    })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('get-user', [])))
    .subscribe((response) => {
      return <User > response;
    });
  return null;
}
```

my issue is that my response firse return null, and later return my response istance.. how I can provide a soluction for this?

Thank you

Comment: you are returning null and then the result. Remove `return null;` and it will works fine. also you shouldn't subscribe in the service. You should remove the `.subscribe` and add `return this.http.get(...)` and subscribing in a component.

Comment: It says I must return something...

Comment: @AlesandroGiordano updated my answer here above. If you are not familiar with angular have a look at this: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getUser` method should return an `Observable<User>`. Something like this:

```
public getUser(): Observable<User> {

  const myHeader = new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.session.getAccessToken(),
  })
  .append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  return this.http.get<User>(API_URL + '/users', { headers: myHeader })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('get-user', []))
    );
}
```

You should `subscribe` to this `Observable<User>` to get the user when you're calling `api.getUser()`. Like this:

```
api.getUser()
  .subscribe(response => this.user = response);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    const myHeader = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.session.getAccessToken(),
    }).append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http
      .get<User>(API_URL + '/users', {headers: myHeader})
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('get-user', []))
      );
  }



api.getUser().subscribe(user => this.user = user);
```

Comment: Type Observable<any[] | User> isn't assignable to Osservable<User>

Comment: Please help me, i'm not so familiar with angular

Comment: @AlesandroGiordano just replace `Observable<User>` to `Observable<any>`

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is set the value of this.user asynchronously. Instead of subscribing to your http call within the getUser method, you should return the Observable from the method. It would look something like this:

```
public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    const myHeader = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.session.getAccessToken(),
    }).append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get<User>(API_URL + '/users', {headers: myHeader})
      .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('get-user', [])));
}

getUser().subscribe((user) => this.user = user);
```

Hope that helps!